# Python Celery worker_main "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error, celery

I am working on an application that is based on Celery and want to initiate the workers from within the main function.  Here is a very simplified version of the code:

```
from celery import Celery

class CoolApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Celery('test', 'amqp://guest@localhost/')

test = CoolApp()

test.app.worker_main()
```

This produces a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` error and I can't figure out why.  Please help.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    test.app.worker_main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 368, in worker_main
    ).execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 281, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 367, in handle_argv
    *self.parse_options(prog_name, argv, command))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 403, in parse_options
    self.parser = self.create_parser(prog_name, command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 419, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 275, in add_arguments
    default=conf.worker_state_db,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 431, in __getitem__
    return getitem(k)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 280, in __getitem__
    return mapping[_key]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  ...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 148, in data
    return self.callback()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 910, in _finalize_pending_conf
    conf = self._conf = self._load_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 923, in _load_config
    self.prepare_config(self.loader.conf), self._preconf,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1208, in loader
    return get_loader_cls(self.loader_cls)(app=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/__init__.py", line 21, in get_loader_cls
    return symbol_by_name(loader, LOADER_ALIASES, imp=import_from_cwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 100, in import_from_cwd
    with cwd_in_path():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 60, in cwd_in_path
    if cwd in sys.path:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Comment: Using celery 4.0.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.3 (Maipo)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can someone please help out with this ?
Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to upgrade the celery 3.1.25 to 4.1.0.
So basically in 4.1.0 few of the packages got deprecated. So make sure you are not using the classes which are deprecatred in the latest version.
In my case I am using **celery.worker.job.Request** which is deprecated in 3.1.25 and now it is **celery.worker.request.Request**

I hope this will help you.